# Clock cycles for a 8bit CPU and memory reads

Tags: verilog, emulation, cpu, 8-bit, cpu-cycles

Is it possible for a 8bit CPU to read memory in less than 3 clock cycles? I know that the 6502 works with an asynchronous memory but what about other 8bit CPUs with clocked memories? Do I need a clock divider to make the CPU slower?

My understanding is that during cycle 1: CPU outputs an address, during cycle 2: memory reads the address then gives the corresponding byte, and during cycle 3: CPU finally receives byte. Is this correct?

Comment: When emulating a CPU you don't have to emulating it down to each cycle, unless the timing of the programs to be executed depends on this. It's perfectly possible to create an emulation in which *every* instruction (even things that normally take a lot of cycles on physical hardware) finishes within one cycle. Furthermore, it's also possible to build a CPU in a way, that a complete memory transaction finishes within on instruction clock cycle (namely by running the memory interface at a multiple of the instruction clock).

Comment: Thank you datenworf, I already created some emulators (NES, GB, C64), but I'm creating this new one to have a better overview of all the signals and then maybe switching to Verilog at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My understanding is that during cycle 1: CPU outputs an address, during cycle 2: memory reads the address then gives the corresponding byte, and during cycle 3: CPU finally receives byte. Is this correct?

That's not quite right. In particular, the CPU must "receive" the byte in the same cycle that the memory has "given" it. Generally, the value is latched with a rising or falling clock edge.

What exactly takes place depends on the instruction that's executing. For example, an LDA immediate takes two cycles. The first cycle, the CPU reads the opcode. The second cycle, the CPU reads the operand and stores it in the accumulator.

Another example: LDA zeropage. The CPU reads the instruction in the first cycle. It reads the address in the second cycle. Then it reads the datum into the accumulator on the third and last cycle of the instruction.

Notice how each cycle is a memory access on the 6502. An address is output, and an 8 bit value is read in or written out. Always.